# HelloFacebookSample wall post request doesn't work after using Friendpicker

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Using facebook SDK 3.5 and Android4 device (samsung xcover2).

I'm trying to pick friends and post to my wall.

**Preconditions**:

- FBAndroid-3.5.apk installed from the SDK, launched and authenticated
- HellofacebookSample.apk: changed canPresentShareDialog flag to force use Request instead of FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder()

`// canPresentShareDialog = FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog()
canPresentShareDialog = false;`

**Steps**:

( I need it this way since I want to restrict allowed viewers)

1. Open sample app
2. click "log in with facebook"
    =>user logged in
3. pick some friends
4. post status update

   => request.executeAsync();

**Result**:
Request is not completed. Entry is not posted. No diagnostic messages.

However, it usually works the other way round: First post and then pick friends.

And depending on unknown variables (outside temp, solar wind?) above main use case might succeed. 
If the sample app is in such mood, force stopping it and restarting sometimes helps. If I run without FBAndroid-3.5.apk, use case usually is much more unreliable.

**I just want a zero state** from where I can run the use case succesfully.

FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder() seems to be working. If it supported viewer restriction, I would use it instead.

**CODE**

Here is the code snippet of the sample application. (I have specifically canPresentShareDialog=false, which could also be done by uninstalling the facebook native apk).

```
private void postStatusUpdate() {
    if (canPresentShareDialog) {
        FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilder().build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
    } else if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
        final String message = getString(R.string.status_update, user.getFirstName(), (new Date().toString()));
        Request request = Request
                .newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, place, tags, new Request.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        showPublishResult(message, response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                    }
                });
        Log.i("MYAPP", "request executeAsync() ");
        request.executeAsync();
    } else {
        pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
    }
}
```

Full Activity can be seen at:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample/src/com/facebook/samples/hellofacebook/HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java

Comment: post the code you tried

Comment: added code, although it's same as in sample app.

Comment: It seems that my restrictive firewall caused this. Who would have thought.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my restrictive firewall caused this. S**t.